# Changing the Content Aware color for Eclipse Dark Theme

Tags: eclipse, themes

So I downloaded the [Eclipse Dark Theme](https://github.com/guari/eclipse-ui-theme) and got the syntax highlighting worked out, but I am having issues when using content assist feature. The blue text on the dark background makes the text very hard to change, and I have tried digging around looking for settings to change this but I could not find any. Can someone give me some advice here?

[image]